# Spin-wave functions of baryons using Young tableaux

Tags: particle-physics, wavefunction

I might be missing some basic knowledge. We mentioned this in our lectures but even upon further questioning I still don't understand it.

We wanted to consider all possible irreducible representations containing $\uparrow \uparrow \downarrow$ s=1/2. We started by getting all the irreducible representations in SU(2) using young tableaux:

[image]

Dimensions of those representations are as follows: (2 $\bigotimes$
2) $\bigotimes$
2 = 4 $\bigoplus$ 2 $\bigoplus$2

And from that, we somehow got the following spin-wave functions:

s = ( |$\uparrow \uparrow \downarrow$> + |$\downarrow \uparrow \uparrow$> + |$\uparrow \downarrow \uparrow$>) $\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$

Ms =  ( |$\uparrow \downarrow \uparrow$> + |$\downarrow \uparrow \uparrow$>  -2|$\uparrow \uparrow \downarrow$> ) $\frac{1}{\sqrt6}$

Ma = (|$\uparrow \downarrow \uparrow$> - |$\downarrow \uparrow \uparrow$>) $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$

I understand how we got s, as it follows from the first young tableaux on the right, which is just a row so all states are fully symmetric.

The second and third tableaux both have symmetry and asymmetry on the exchange of states, but I have no idea how to derive Ms and Ma from them even whilst knowing the rules in the literature. Could someone explain to me the process of how Ms and Ma is derived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the $J=3/2, M_J=1/2$ state.
To find the $J=1/2, M_J=1/2$ states write
$$
\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle = \alpha \vert \uparrow\uparrow\downarrow\rangle +\beta \vert \uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\rangle +\gamma \vert\downarrow\uparrow\uparrow\rangle\, .
$$
Because $M_J=J$ for this state, it must be killed by $J_+=J_+^{(1)}+J_+^{(2)}+J_+^{(3)}$, providing *one* relation between $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$.  It must also be orthogonal to the $S=3/2,M_J=1/2$ state, providing a second relation between the coefficients.

If you do this you will find that indeed (up to normalization) there are two solutions, one of which is your Ms and the other one is your Ma.  Note that orthogonal linear combinations of Ms and Ma are also possible, although this will change some of the symmetries of your states under interchange of particles 1 and 2.

If you're looking to work directly with Young diagrams, you will need to Young symmetrizers (aka Young projectors).  You first start with the two semi-standard Young tableaux

[image]

Now it seems your Ms and Ma are actually labelled by the symmetries under permutation of the first two particles, i.e. by representations of the $S_2$ subgroup containing $\{\hat 1,P_{12}\}$, so this will affect the ordering of the projection operators.

Start with the first Young diagram.  Since going down columns is an antisymmetrization, one state compatible with this tableau is $\vert\phi_s\rangle=\vert \uparrow \uparrow \downarrow\rangle$.  Symmetrizing along the rows and antisymmetrizing down columns will produce the operator
$\hat \Pi_s=(1+P_{12})(1-P_{13})$  which, applied to $\vert\phi_s\rangle$, will yield
$$
2\vert \uparrow\uparrow\downarrow\rangle -\vert \downarrow\uparrow\uparrow\rangle -\vert\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\rangle
$$
which is , up to a phase, your Ms and is symmetric under permutation of particles 1 and 2.  Clearly $P_{12}\hat \Pi_s=\hat \Pi_s$ so you're guaranteed to get a state symmetric under the interchange of 1 and 2.

To get the second state, start with the Young diagram, and use  $\vert\phi_a\rangle=\vert \uparrow \downarrow\uparrow\rangle$.  Symmetrizing along the rows and antisymmetrizing down columns will produce the operator
$\hat \Pi_a=(1-P_{12})(1+P_{13})$  which, applied to $\vert\phi_a\rangle$, will yield
$$
\vert\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\rangle - \vert \downarrow\uparrow\uparrow\rangle
$$
which is your Ma, antisymmetric under permutation of particles 1 and 2.  Note again that this time $P_{12}\hat \Pi_a=-\hat \Pi_a$ so you're guaranteed to get a state antisymmetric under the interchange of 1 and 2.

Comment: I would like to thank you, as I was struggling with this for a long time.

Just one correction though - on the Ms solution, the last |$\uparrow \uparrow \downarrow$> should be |$\uparrow \downarrow \uparrow$> based on the lecture notes and based on my own solution following your procedure.

Comment: @SSnarlies fixed thanks.

Comment: Thank you for editing the answer; but you changed the wrong thing.
The described change should have happened on the $\phi_s$ not $\phi_a$.

So: $(1+P_{12})(1-P_{13}) | \phi_s>$ = $2|\uparrow \uparrow \downarrow > - |\downarrow \uparrow \uparrow > - | \uparrow \downarrow \uparrow>$

Comment: I only now saw that I can submit an edit, if it it approved it fixes the problems.

ZeroTheHero you are awesome!

Comment: @SSnarlies Thanks.  I could not find my notes and it’s quite possible errors remained.

Comment: @SSnarlies  "ZeroTheHero you are awesome!" can I quote you on this?  ;)

Comment: you have my full permission to quote me anytime. The allowed uses of the quote also include the creation of slogans, selling of merch etc :P